# How to use a bash profile function to connect remotely and access the remote terminal

Tags: bash, function, remote-access

I want to write a `bash function` locally, so when I run this function the first command is to get connected to an ubuntu Remote Desktop through `ssh`.

In a nutshell:

```
    my_func () {
    ssh blah blah blah;
    echo $HOME;
}
```

The desired output is sth like `/home/ubuntu`, but I get nothing. So I have the impression that `my_func` works only locally, because when I exit the Remote Desktop then I get my local `$HOME` directory.

Answer (score 0):

ssh can take arguments that represent commands to run on the remote host. You probably want something like this:

```
my_func() { ssh user@host sh -c 'echo $HOME'; }
```

Where I'm using single quotes to prevent the variable from being expanded on the local machine.

Comment: Why the additional `sh -c`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Though it seems to work for `echo $HOME`,  in the Remote Desktop I have set another environment variable and when I `echo` that variable instead of `$HOME`, I get nothing printed.

Comment: You need a shell because `$HOME` is a shell variable. This environment variable you set, is it set in just that one session? Or did you set in, for example, your bash `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`? If it's just in the one session, then a new ssh session will not be able to see that variable.

Comment: experimenting: I think `ssh user@host 'echo $HOME'` will work

Comment: @glennjackman, yes, IMHO, `ssh user@host 'echo $HOME'` should work.